# Firebase help - multiple databases

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a number of difficulties with Firebase in my iOS app in Objective C.

The app used Firebase for a custom login database.

The app originally connected to a firebase database containing usernames and passwords.

I have since introduced another connection to firebase for realtime retrieval of data into a tableView. This is on a separate firebase project. I am not sure how to have both databases as part of one project.

I have added the GoogleService-Info.plist and it only allows for one DATABASE_URL. Is it possible to have multiple DATABASE_URL's? I would like to switch between the projects when necessary.

The code for the login is based on firebase version 1.0. The app connected to firebase via a 'webservice' url.

I have since updated to the latest release of Firebase and the code is now broken. I have updated some of the deprecated references and cleared most of the errors.

I am experiencing errors when I run the app and attempt to login however. There is no connection to the url of the firebase project for the login.

I will add the code for the login function below.

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    if (txtEmail.text.length > 0 && txtToken.text.length > 0) {
        if ([sharedHelper isConnectedToInternet]) {
            [self.activityView startAnimating];

            //If the user has purchased but not logged in, when they do login we want to add their purchases to their user
            NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            [settings setObject:txtEmail.text forKey:@"userEmail"];
            [settings setObject:txtToken.text forKey:@"userToken"];

            NSMutableDictionary *purchase = [settings objectForKey:@"UnRecordedPurchase"];
            NSString *subscriptionLength = @"0";
            NSString *expiryDate = @"";
            NSString *receiptData = @"";
            if (purchase)
            {
                subscriptionLength = [purchase objectForKey:@"subscriptionLength"];
                expiryDate = [purchase objectForKey:@"expiryDate"];
                receiptData = [purchase objectForKey:@"receiptData"];
            }
            [settings setObject:nil forKey:@"UnRecordedPurchase"];
            [settings synchronize];

            //Firebase *firebase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kLOGINWEBSERVICEURL];
            FIRDatabaseReference *firebase= [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

            [firebase observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
                [self.activityView stopAnimating];

                if (snapshot.value == [NSNull null]) {
                    // No data found
                    NSString *errorMessage = @"Unable to check login details - please contact support@ambay.com";
                    [self showStatusMessage:errorMessage];

                } else {
                    NSMutableArray *matchingEmailChildren = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

                    for (FIRDataSnapshot *child in snapshot.children) {
                        NSDictionary *dict = child.value;

                        // Check the email address

                        if ([[[dict valueForKey:@"Email"] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[self.txtEmail.text lowercaseString]]) {
                            [matchingEmailChildren addObject:child];
                        }
                    }

                    if ([matchingEmailChildren count] > 0) {
                        NSMutableArray *matchingTokenChildren = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

                        // Check for matching token
                        for (FIRDataSnapshot *child in matchingEmailChildren) {
                            NSDictionary *dict = child.value;

                            if ([[[dict valueForKey:@"Token"] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[self.txtToken.text lowercaseString]]) {

                                [matchingTokenChildren addObject:child];
                            }
                        }

                        if ([matchingTokenChildren count] > 0) {
                            BOOL loginSuccess = NO;

                            // Check expiry date
                            for (FIRDataSnapshot *child in matchingTokenChildren) {
                                NSDictionary *dict = child.value;

                                // Get today's date, just as the date without time values
                                NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
                                NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                           fromDate:[NSDate date]];
                                [components setHour:12];
                                [components setMinute:0];
                                [components setSecond:0];

                                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

                                NSDate *todaysDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

                                // Format expiry date to just the date component

                                components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                         fromDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:[dict valueForKey:@"ExpiryDate"]]];

                                [components setHour:12];
                                [components setMinute:0];
                                [components setSecond:0];

                                NSDate *expiryDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

                                if ([expiryDate compare:todaysDate] == NSOrderedSame || [expiryDate compare:todaysDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {

                                    NSMutableDictionary *userDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                                    [userDict setObject:self.txtEmail.text forKey:@"Username"];
                                    [userDict setObject:self.txtToken.text forKey:@"Token"];

                                    // Change format of expiry date for compatibility purposes and convert to string to save locally
                                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                                    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
                                    NSString *expiryDateAsString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:expiryDate];

                                    [userDict setObject:expiryDateAsString forKey:@"ExpiryDate"];

                                    [sharedHelper addUserWithDictionary:userDict fromCloud:NO];

                                    [self loginSuccess];

                                    loginSuccess = YES;

                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (loginSuccess == NO) {
                                NSString *errorMessage = @"Your Annual Subscription has expired. Contact support@ambay.com";
                                [self showStatusMessage:errorMessage];
                            }

                        } else {
                            NSString *errorMessage = @"Your Code is incorrect for this email address.";
                            [self showStatusMessage:errorMessage];

                            [self.txtToken becomeFirstResponder];
                        }

                    } else {
                        NSString *errorMessage = @"We cannot find your email address on our system.\r\n\r\n For assistance contact support@ambay.com";
                        [self showStatusMessage:errorMessage];

                        [self.txtEmail becomeFirstResponder];
                    }
                }

            } withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSString *errorMessage = @"Unable to check login details - please contact support@ambay.com";
                [self showStatusMessage:errorMessage];
            }];

        } else {
            NSString *errorMessage = @"Unable to validate email & code details. Please check your internet connection.";
            [self showStatusMessage:errorMessage];
        }
    } else {
        NSString *errorMessage = @"Please enter email address and code.";
        [self showStatusMessage:errorMessage];
    }
}
```

Could you please point out any errors in the above code.

Thanks
WG

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the one extra database, then you should look into Firebase Auth. It allows sign in with email and password as well as providers such as Google, Facebook, Twitter, and GitHub. Then you would only need the one database URL and then a reference to Firebase Auth.